# Call a Java SpringBoot server method from a JavaScript script on a website

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, spring-boot

I'm working on a submenu on my website, that has 5 options, each of them is name of a game. When user selects an option, I want my server to print a name of the game, that user selected. Here i have two problems:

1. I don't know why after click on a submenu option, I always get the
   first game name.
2. I don't know how to send a request from a JS to my Spring Boot application, which is a server. 
   Can you help me? Here is my code:

```html
<ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="selectGameSubmenu">
    <li data-option="League of Legends">
        <a href="#"><img src="../../../static/images/league_of_legends/leagueoflegends_icon.png"
                         alt="" style="width:16px;height:16px"> League of Legends</a>
    </li>
    <li data-option="Teamfight Tactics">
        <a href="#"><img src="../../../static/images/teamfight_tactics/teamfighttactics_icon.png"
                         alt="" style="width:16px;height:16px"> Teamfight Tactics</a>
    </li>
    <li data-option="Legends of Runterra">
        <a href="#"><img src="../../../static/images/legends_of_runterra/legendsofruneterra_icon.png"
                         alt="" style="width:16px;height:16px"> Leagends of Runterra</a>
    </li>
    <li data-option="Valorant">
        <a href="#"><img src="../../../static/images/valorant/valorant_icon.png"
                         alt="" style="width:16px;height:16px"> Valorant</a>
    </li>
    <li data-option="Counter Strike">
        <a href="#"><img src="../../../static/images/counter_strike/counterstrike_icon.png"
                         alt="" style="width:16px;height:16px"> Counter Strike</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$("#selectGameSubmenu").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var option = $("#selectGameSubmenu li").data("option");
    console.log(option);
});
```

```
@PostMapping("/change-game")
public String changeGame(@RequestParam String game){
    System.out.println("Selected option: " + game);
    return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem lies under your click event listener. So whenever you click on your ul elements it will trigger but as you define such a selector `$("#selectGameSubmenu li")` **it will always return your first child of `ul`** which is `League of Legends`.

To fix it you should modify it a bit. First of all, instead of adding event listener in your `ul` **you should add an event listener in your `li`** and then **get the specific clicked item by using `$(this)`**, the output should be something like this:

```js
$("li").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var option = $(this).data('option');
  console.log(option);
});
```

Your second problem is simple, **for communicating between your backend and frontend application you should use something like `ajax`. An `ajax` request will help to retrieve and send data between applications.** For more information about it, you can read either of these articles: [JQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), [Site point](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/), or [Free code camp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/jquery-ajax-post-method/).

Your request will be something like this:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url, // Your end point address 
  data: data, // Your data
  success: success // Your actions after data send successfully 
});
```